# weighting a single vertices model?

Tags: modeling, animation, bones, vertices, weight-painting

[enter link description here](https://youtu.be/UPenxxZbyf0)

[image]

[image]

I'm having trouble weighting this model that i pulled from an fbx file sight....the other hand seems to be okay but this hand seems to be a troublemaker...the blend file is attached if you want to disect my issue. if im doing the weight painting wrong...please tell me how to correct my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glove has thickness, that's probably why it struggles to get a correct weight when parenting *With Automatic Weights*:

[image]

To remove this thickness, select all the outer faces, invert the selection, delete:

[image]

Now unparent the glove object with *Clear and Keep Transformation* option, apply the scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>):

[image]

Flip the normals in *Edit* mode, back to *Object* mode, select the glove, shift select the armature and parent *With Automatic Weights* and it will work.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151685/discussion-on-answer-by-moonboots-weighting-a-single-vertices-model); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.